# Cadastro com campos repetidos, como fazer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Tenho um cadastro no sistema que estou desenvolvendo que terá campos repetidos, gostaria de obter ajuda nesta implementação.

Esta tela chama-se Sequencia que tem os seguintes campos

---

Data

Numero Sequencia

Lote

Nome = Lado A | Tipo | Câmara

Nome = Lado B | Tipo | Câmara

---

**Todo o cadastro de Sequencia que será realizado sempre terá Lado A e Lado B.**

[image: Imagem ilustrando a tela Sequencia]

---

Criei um classe para que as Views possa enxergar as classes correspondentes ao cadastro.

**Classe SequenciaViewModel**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace GerenciamentoDeQuartos.Models
{
    public class SequenciaViewModel
    {
        public SequenciaViewModel()
        {
            Lado_A.Nome = "Lado A";
            Lado_B.Nome = "Lado B";
        }

        public Lote Lote { get; set; }
        public List<Lote> LoteList { get; set; }

        public Sequencia Sequencia { get; set; }
        public List<Sequencia> SequenciaList { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tipo Lado A")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public Lado Lado_A { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tipo Lado B")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public Lado Lado_B { get; set; }
        public List<Lado> LadoList { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Camara A")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public Camara Camara_A { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Camara B")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public Camara Camara_B { get; set; }
        public List<Camara> CamaraList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View de cadastro de Sequencia ( Create )**

```
@model GerenciamentoDeQuartos.Models.SequenciaViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Sequencia</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Lado_A.Nome)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Lado_B.Nome)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sequencia.DataAbate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sequencia.DataAbate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sequencia.DataAbate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sequencia.NumeroSequencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sequencia.NumeroSequencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sequencia.NumeroSequencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sequencia.Lote, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sequencia.Lote, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sequencia.Lote, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lado_A.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lado_A.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lado_A.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lado_A, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TipoLadoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lado_A.TipoLadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Camara_A, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CamaraId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lado_A.CamaraId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lado_B.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lado_A.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lado_A.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lado_B.TipoLadoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TipoLadoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lado_B.TipoLadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Camara_B, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CamaraId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lado_B.CamaraId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```